# can you get more than one download URL at once in firestore storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage

I have a path in my bucket that has 10 images can I get the downlead URL of all those 10 images at once in a similar way when you for each doc fields in getDoc() ? or it it stricted to only one at time and to only a specific file name refrence?

```js
const storage = getStorage();
getDownloadURL(ref(storage, 'images/1.jpg'))
  .then((url) => {
  }
  
  
  
const storage = getStorage();
getDownloadURL(ref(storage, 'images/'))
  .then((url) => {
  // all the images inside path images/ 
  }
```

Comment: Given how the data is stored, I expect that there can be only one download URL per file at a time. But I'm hoping someone can answer more definitively. --- Aside from that, this sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though. What are you trying to accomplish by generating multiple download URLs for the same file?

Comment: no i have a drop off menu that has 7 images, and I want to add the url in advance to be the src of those 7 images.

Comment: But that sounds like 7 different files, so each would have their own download URL wouldn't they?